# if (counter ) is the same as If (counter !=0)?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm learning c++, and I wanted to know whether the statement
"if(counter)" is the same as "if (counter!=0)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `counter` is a built-in primitive type (`int`, `double`, pointers), yes, it means the same thing. If it's not a primitive type, they could mean completely different things (whatever `operator bool` and the comparator defined for comparing with something implicitly convertable from `int` happen to return).